# Array is set but not defined

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using jQuery Isotope to filter product photos. I've had to change the example to use select boxes, which works great, but now I need to adapt the code from the example that has multiple filtering attributes.

This is the example code that works:

```
   $(function(){

    var $container = $('#container'),
        filters = {};

    $container.isotope({
      itemSelector : '.color-shape',
      masonry: {
        columnWidth: 80
      }
    });

    // filter buttons
    $('.filter a').click(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      // don't proceed if already selected
      if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
        return;
      }

      var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
      // change selected class
      $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $this.addClass('selected');

      // store filter value in object
      // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
      var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
      filters[ group ] = $this.attr('data-filter-value');
      // convert object into array
      var isoFilters = [];
      for ( var prop in filters ) {
        isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
      }
      var selector = isoFilters.join('');
      $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

      return false;
    });
});
```

And here is my code that doesn't work.

```
$(function() {

    var $container = $('#productsContainer'),
        filters = {};
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });
    $('.filter select').change(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set'),
            $container = $('#productsContainer');
        var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
        filters[group] = $this.attr('data-filter-value');
        // convert object into array
        var isoFilters = [];
        for (var prop in filters) {
            isoFilters.push(filters[prop])
        }
        var selector = isoFilters.join('');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I've tracked it down to the isoFilters array items being added, but they are empty. I can't figure out what the problem is.

The code works if I replace this line:

```
    var selector = isoFilters.join('');
```

With this:

```
        var selector = $("option:selected",this).attr("data-filter-value");
```

But that doesn't allow to to filter by both groups, only one.

I'm kind of over my head on this, hoping for some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what what going on. This line wasn't selecting the proper attribute from the select box.

```
filters[group] = $this.attr('data-filter-value');
```

I had to change it to this:

```
filters[ group ] = $("option:selected",this).attr('data-filter-value');
```